# AngularJS: Unexpected directive scope creation duplication

Tags: angularjs, scope

I am experiencing some troubles understanding why angular is creating two scopes for some of my directives. My original code is messy and consist a lot of "temp" sections in it, so I created a plnkr to illustrate just the problem that I am experiencing. Here is the link: 
http://plnkr.co/edit/gKMcCyRlGHwuKAQ6te76?p=preview 
(please keep in mind the code is just for the illustration)

[My Problem] 
executing the simple example leads to creating 5 scopes. 
1. Scope 002 - I believe this scope is created to serve as a root scope when angular encounter the ng-app directive. 
2. Scope 003 - I believe this scope is created as controller's scope. In my case HomeController's scope. 
3. Scope 004 - I believe this scope is created when angular parse my **group** directive. Since the directive is defined with "scope: true", then this scope is created for it to store it's models. In this scope one can access the sectionID (that is set in preLink phase in the directive's code). 
4. Scope 005 - I have no idea why angular created that scope for me. 
5. Scope 006 - This scope is created for my **testInput** directive. **The parent of this scope is scope 005.** Sadly this scope is totally unaware for the information stored in scope 004, hence in this scope sectionID is undefined.

[My Expectations] 
Well, I expected Scope 005 to be missing and scope 006 to be a child scope of scope 004. What I need is to set some information in the scope of my group directive and then access that information from within the elements that are nested inside the group.

[My Question] 
Does anyone know why Scoope 005 is created in first place? I think my problem comes due to my poor knowledge on how angular manage the scopes, but from the information I found and read in the net I couldn't find the answer.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The group directive has `transclude: true`, and transclusion will create a "transcluded" scope, that's the `Scope 005`.

Comment: OK I understand that. That way Scope 005 is sibling of Scope 004. Then my question is - Is it possible Scope 004 to  have siblings other from Scope 005.